# Rails collection_select 2 words in name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have collectio select:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:supplier_id, Supplier.all, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "Select supplier"}) %>
```

How to make words name and surname instead only name?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your model has `:name` and `:surname` attributes, the simplest way would be to add a method e.g. `:full_name` to it, like so:

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def full_name
    "#{name} #{surname}"
  end
end
```

Then use `:full_name` instead of `:name` in your `collection_select` arguments.